# Qt ошибка сборки под Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, qtcreator

Создал небольшое приложение на Qt 5.7
На винде работает, а под Adnroid даже не собирается.
В качестве андроид девайса использую Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 Pro.
Ошибка:

```
Error: Target id 'android--1' is not valid. Use 'android.bat list targets' to get the target ids.
Generating Android Package
  Input file: C:/Users/NoGameNoLife/Documents/build-untitled1-Android_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_7_0-Release/android-libuntitled1.so-deployment-settings.json
  Output directory: C:/Users/NoGameNoLife/Documents/build-untitled1-Android_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_7_0-Release/android-build/
  Application binary: C:/Users/NoGameNoLife/Documents/build-untitled1-Android_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_7_0-Release/libuntitled1.so
  Android build platform: android--1
  Install to device: No
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
Warning: Android platform 'android--1' does not exist in SDK.
Building the android package failed!
  -- For more information, run this command with --verbose.

19:40:47: Процесс «C:\Qt\5.7\android_armv7\bin\androiddeployqt.exe» завершился с кодом 14.
Ошибка при сборке/установке проекта untitled1 (комплект: Android для armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt 5.7.0) )
```

Во время выполнения этапа «Сборка Android APK»

Comment: Откуда эта ошибка и когда возникает? Как собраете Qt? Что происходит если подставить `target` из `andoid.bat`?

Comment: Покажите скрин настроек проекта

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Нужно было через SDK скачать API Android, и в настройках указать на эту сборку.